# Pass value two textbox's from one variable value

Tags: c#, siemens, s7-1200

I have an encoder connected from Siemens PLC with data block "DB1.DBD56".

My problem is, the two textbox has the same result or value.

Scenario:

Read Before 1seconds and
Read After  1seconds

I want the result like this:

[For reference]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK9zU.png)

[PLC Ladder]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGN62.png)

```
#region EVENT TO START READING THE ENCODER

    private void timer_anvilState_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Edata_convertion();
            read_lastweld_result();

            bool anvilState = (bool)plc_s7_1200.Read("DB1.DBX68.4");

            if (plc_s7_1200.IsConnected)
            {
                if (anvilState == true)
                {
                    timer_OneCycleProcess.Start(); //STATE MACHINE TIMER
                }
                else
                {
                    timer_OneCycleProcess.Stop();
                    command = "IDLE";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please check between PC and PLC connection " + "\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    #region READ BEFORE
    public void Read_Before()
    {
        if (plc_s7_1200.IsConnected)
        {
            bool anvilState = (bool)plc_s7_1200.Read("DB1.DBX68.4");

            if (anvilState == true)
            {
                string Edata = string.Format("{0:0.0}", convertTomm);
                txtbefore.Text = Edata;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region READ AFTER
    public void Read_After()
    {
        bool gen_US_on = (bool)plc_s7_1200.Read("DB1.DBX78.2");
        if (gen_US_on == true)
        {
            string Edata = string.Format("{0:0.0}", convertTomm);
            txtafterWeld.Text = Edata;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Question is unclear. Where do you want to write the same value to both text boxes? At no time do you read "DBD56" so it's unclear why that detail was included.

Comment: I have included a picture what is my expectation. Also, I've already emphasizing my issue. Anyway, I was resolved my issue What I did was, I added a pulse timer between %Q0.2 and move instruction with 1 second time and added another pulse timer and move instruction with 500ms time, my c# program read it of timer event. The two move instructions added are different variable or address. Please see my attached picture PLC ladder that the previous address I've used is "DBD56". The timer "one cycle process is a state machine"

Comment: Hello GMK, could you please post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

Only revised the PLC ladder as stated my replied at comment section.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUBtg.png

My C# program nothing changes.

Sharing my basic state machine code

```
#region ONE CYCLE PROCESS
private void timer_OneCycleProcess_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (command)
    {
        case "IDLE":
            command = "BEFORE";
            break;

        case "BEFORE":
            before();
            command = "AFTER";
            break;
        case "AFTER":

            after();

            prev_result();

            read_maintenanceCounter();

            read_outputCounter();

            command = "SAVE";
            break;

        case "SAVE":

            command = "STOP";

            save();

            save_history();
            break;
        case "STOP":
            timer_OneCycleProcess.Stop();
            plc_s7_1200.Write("DB1.DBX38.0", 0);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
#endregion
```